# How to prevent sendmail from sending bounce messages to domains in the "To:" headers of received messages?

Tags: email, sendmail

We are running a Debian Bullseye server that handles the email for our domain. We are using `sendmail` as MTA. We have disabled relaying and accept email messages only after SMTP authentication.

Today, by accident, we have noticed an interesting situation which was difficult to understand. The following seems to have happened:

A spammer has sent a message to us. During the SMTP session between his and our server, he used a **valid envelope-to address** of the form `user@our-domain.com`. But the `To:` header in that message was different and contained an address which did not belong to our domain and thus cannot be handled by our email system, e.g. `unknown@somebody-else.com`. The envelope-from address was the same as that in the `From:` and the `Return-Path:` headers of the message.

To summarize:

```
Envelope-From:        spammer@sender-domain.com
'From' header:        spammer@sender-domain.com
'Return-Path' header: spammer@sender-domain.com
Envelope-To:          user@our-domain.com
'To' header:          unknown@somebody-else.com
```

Now we had the following problem: We **believe** that `sendmail` tried to send a bounce message to `somebody-else.com`, eventually to notify them that the message to `unknown@somebody-else.com` could not be delivered.

We were not able yet to find out the complete recipient address for that bounce message, because the DNS resolution for `somebody-else.com` was failing. That's the accident which made us notify the problem in the first place: In turn, we have got a bounce message from our system because the domain `somebody-else.com` could not be resolved.

Hence the bold "We believe" in the paragraph above: The only indication that sendmail actually tried to send a bounce message to `somebody-else.com` is the fact that it tried to resolve that domain name. Since it has no reason to try that if it doesn't want to send a message we have come to the conclusion that it wanted to send a bounce message to that domain.

**This assumption may be wrong.** In this case, we would be grateful if somebody could shortly explain other reasons which could sendmail make try to resolve that domain name.

If our assumption is correct: How can we prevent `sendmail` from sending bounce messages to the domains in the `To:` headers of received messages (unless that domain's email is handled by our system)?

[ Side note: We'd like to prevent `sendmail` from doing so because we are afraid that it attaches the original message to the bounce message, which would allow spammers to **abuse our SMTP server** to send their rubbish at least to the postmasters of the domains in the `To:` headers of the spam messages they send us. ]

**UPDATE 2022-12-19**

We are regularly getting such messages and have investigated the situation further. Fortunately, our system is not sending backscatter spam. We have examined several dozens of such cases, and in no case `sendmail` did send back a message to the domain in the `To:` header of the received spam message.

There must be something special about the specific message that made me write this question and the other messages we have examined. We have noticed two differences:

1. The other spam messages we have examined had been delivered to a catch-all inbox we have created for that purpose. The spam message this question is about has **not** been delivered to any mailbox although the envelope-to was the same as in other messages which **have** been delivered.
2. `sendmail` (obviously) could not resolve the domain in the `To:` header of the message this question is about. But (again obviously) it didn't have that problem with the domains in the `To:` headers of the other messages we have investigated.

Currently we suspect that something weird starts to go on only in cases where `sendmail` can't resolve the domain name in the `To:` headers of received spam messages.

Comment: Could there have been a **Return-Path** field that was the same as the **To** header which took your focus away from the true fault? - I don't think there's any reason a mail server (be it Sendmail, Exchange, or anything else) would try to send a delivery failure email to the **To** address which clearly has failed. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-58

Comment: Thinking about it, you said **Envelope-From** was valid, so why didn't Sendmail deliver the email to the specified recipient? - Sounds like something else is going or Sendmail read the content of the message and send it on to the To. *The envelope contains whatever information is needed to accomplish transmission and delivery.*  - **To** should be for mail clients to display.  You wouldn't expect a postman to open a letter and read who it is addressed to on the letter itself... Ignore the question, this answer explains it and gives a test example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851602/3457477

Comment: At first, thanks for caring, and +1. Answering your first comment: The return path in the message the spammer had sent us was `spammer@sender-domain.com`. Thank you very much for that hint; I'll add this to the question and reply to your second comment afterwards.

Comment: Your second comment: I have no clue whether the Envelope-From address was valid (spammers could fake it); I only said that the Envelope-To address was valid. The difference between envelope and header addresses is clear to us, which actually is the reason for asking the question: Why does sendmail try to resolve the domain part of an address in the `To:` header? - In the meantime, I have updated the question (before, it was not clear enough that we only **assumed** that sendmail tried to send a bounce message, based on the fact that it tried to resolve that domain name).

Comment: Sorry, me asking **Envelope-From** was a mistype and should have been **Envelope-To**. (1) Did the email actually arrive at the mailbox specified in the Envelope-To? (2) Have you tried the test example on your own mailbox? You would be in control of every step and see if it tries to bounce the message if the 'To' filed is for an unknown domain, but the Envelope-To is your mailbox (`sendmail you@your-domain.com < mail.txt`). (3) Are you using Sendmail as the MUA? I also came across https://serverfault.com/q/717053/442803 - Sounds very similar to what you're experiencing.

Comment: What you are describing is called Backscatter Spam.  You should not be relaying mail for unknown hosts, ever, even if they sneakily pretend to be a user @ your domain. Only relay for known good hosts (e.g. your LAN) and optionally for **authenticated** users too.  You should not even be accepting such mail - i.e. you should reject it with a 5XX code rather than accept and bounce.  Once your system accepts a message, it has only three possible results: 1. deliver the message, 2. bounce it if it can't be delivered, or 3. discard it.  The second result is the source of backscatter-spam.

Comment: See [Backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)) - and note that if your server is a source of backscatter, it is no better than a spammer's own server and deserves to be blacklisted.  Also worth reading: [Simple Authentication and Security Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) - SASL is good for authenticating users not on your LAN who need to relay through your mail server (e.g. laptop users who are off-site - at home or on the road or whatever)

Comment: @cas Thank you very much. We've been very careful when configuring our email system. We now have investigated the logs further. We regularly get such spam messages and have examined several dozens of such cases: **In no case, our system has sent back a message** to the domain in the `To:` header. There must be something special about the message which made me write the question. The only difference between that specific message and the others seems to be that the domain name in the `To:` header could not be resolved. We'll try to find out why sendmail tries to resolve it at all ...

Comment: Is your mail server configured to honour the long-deprecated `Errors-To:` header?  IIRC, sendmail stopped doing that by default back in the 90s (but I could be mistaken about that, it's been a very long time since I last used sendmail...I briefly tried qmail - good ideas fundamentally flawed by the authors' idiosyncrasies - and then switched to postfix when it came out).

Comment: @cas Sorry for the late reply. Our mail server does not honor `Errors-To:`, and there is no such header in any message. We have researched again and now believe that we did not interpret the situation correctly. Probably that bounce message told us that the original message could not be delivered to **`user@our-domain.com`** because the domain **`somebody-else.com`** could not be resolved. We still don't know why SM tries to resolve that domain, though. We have DKIM and SPF checks for incoming messages, but these AFAIK only access records in the `Envelope-From` domain, not the `To:` domain.